# How do I set the title on an AsyncDisplayKit ASButtonNode?

Tags: ios, swift, asyncdisplaykit

I can set the title for the normal state with this:

```
let buttonTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Book", attributes: attributes)
buttonNode.titleNode.attributedText = buttonTitle
```

However this doesn't set the title for the button's disabled state. To accomplish this, I tried adding the following:

```
buttonNode.setAttributedTitle(buttonTitle, for: .disabled)
```

However this then removes the tile for the normal state. There is no `ASControlState.normal`.

How can I set the button's title to be the same in all states?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button title can be set for all states by setting an empty array for the ASControlState:

```
let buttonTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Book", attributes: attributes)
buttonNode.setAttributedTitle(buttonTitle, for: [])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fileprivate var noteButtonNode : ASButtonNode = ASButtonNode()

let attributedTitle : NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString(
            string: "Book",
            attributes: [
                NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.init(name: Fonts.Your_font, size: 16)!,
                NSForegroundColorAttributeName: Colors.Your_Color
            ])
        noteButtonNode.setAttributedTitle(attributedTitle, for: ASControlState())
```